# django background tasks in views

Tags: python, django, background-task

I have a django view which displays some info from the associated model and also grabs some info from another web app via the rest api.

To do this, at the moment I am overriding the `get_context_data` function like so:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ListProjectsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['issues'] = phab.get_recent_issues() # call the phabricator api to get the most recent issues
```

This causes the page to take 5-10s to load, which is unacceptable.

Is there a way I can display the page while calling the external api in the background and updating the view when the data is available??

Even better, is there a way I can poll the external api at a regular interval and automatically update the page? Then I dont need to rely on the user refreshing the page to get the latest data...

Comment: Use `AJAX` requests may be one sollution

Comment: You want either ajax + polling or websockets.

Comment: i.e...this needs to be handled client side with javascript?